# How to pass Core Data object from one SwiftUI view to another through environment property

Tags: core-data, swiftui

First I should say my current code works fine. Here's what I have in my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Pokemon.id, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var pokedex: FetchedResults<Pokemon>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(pokedex) { pokemon in
                NavigationLink(value: pokemon) {
                    Text(pokemon.name!.capitalized)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Pokedex")
            .navigationDestination(for: Pokemon.self, destination: { pokemon in
                PokemonDetail(pokemon: pokemon) // NOTICE THIS
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
           .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext) // ALSO THIS
    }
}
```

The part to notice is the line inside the .navigationDestination modifier where I am passing the pokemon object to the PokemonDetail view. I don't want to have to do that, and I'll explain why in a bit.

Also notice in the preview I am able to use a sample Pokemon that I created in the PersistenceController specifically for the preview, through the .environment modifier. I want to be able to do this same thing in my PokemonDetail view, which right now looks like this:

```
struct PokemonDetail: View {
    let pokemon: Pokemon // NOTE: I don't like this property.
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(pokemon.background)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 0)
            
            AsyncImage(url: pokemon.sprite) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 0)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
            .padding(.top, 100)
        }
    }
}

struct PokemonDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Pokemon> = Pokemon.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        
        let result = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        
        return PokemonDetail(pokemon: result.first!) // NOTE: I want to use the same .environment modifier I used in ContentView instead of having to create this context and fetch request.
    }
}
```

Notice how throughout this file I am using that pokemon property that was passed from the previous view. And in the preview I have to fetch a pokemon to use.

If I could, I'd much rather do another @FetchRequest here in the PokemonDetail view and just somehow fetch the Pokemon I tapped on from the ContentView.

And I'd also like to use that same .environment modifier in my PokemonDetail preview instead of having to set up a whole new context and fetch request just to fetch a Pokemon for my preview.

One thought I had was to add an @Environment property to the top of my ContentView, and then add it to the PokemonDetail view with an .environment modifier, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext // NEW LINE

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Pokemon.id, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var pokedex: FetchedResults<Pokemon>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(pokedex) { pokemon in
                NavigationLink(value: pokemon) {
                    Text(pokemon.name!.capitalized)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Pokedex")
            .navigationDestination(for: Pokemon.self, destination: { pokemon in
                PokemonDetail() // CHANGE: pokemon argument was removed
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext) // NEW LINE
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
           .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

But still, in the PokemonDetail, I don't know how I would identify which Pokemon was tapped on so I could show the correct information.

My question is, is this even possible, and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: Wrap it with ObservedObject this is inevitable with CoreData, you can use an NSFetchedResultsController and move the request to an ObservableObject but the wrapper instead of the let is still needed. CoreData objects are reference they need the ObservedObject wrapper for each object. The Published wrapper for the array cannot observe the variables of each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do that with `.environmentObject` modifier, bacause CoreData objects confirm to `ObservableObject` protocol, so

1. injected

```
.navigationDestination(for: Pokemon.self, destination: { pokemon in
    PokemonDetail()
       .environmentObject(pokemon)    // << here !!
})
```

2. used

```
struct PokemonDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var pokemon: Pokemon // << here !!
    
    var body: some View {
// ...
```

3. in preview as well

```
struct PokemonDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        // ... create preview `pokemon` 

        return PokemonDetail()
            .environmentObject(pokemon)    // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't really fix my main issue, which is that I have to "create preview pokemon" when I already have a perfectly good sample Pokemon in my PersistenceController. Is there any way to use that PersistenceController sample pokemon in other views besides just the ContentView?

Comment: I'm going to mark this one correct because you answered one of my main questions. As far as I can tell the other thing I was asking isn't possible but your solution makes it much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

`@ObservedObject` is like `@FetchRequest` but it works on one managed object. `body` is called when any property of the object changes.

```
struct PokemonDetail: View {
    @ObservedObject var pokemon: Pokemon
```

You can tidy the code in preview into an extension of `NSManagedObjectContext`, e.g.

```
struct PokemonDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
        
        return PokemonDetail(pokemon: context.firstPokemon) 
    }
}

extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    var firstPokemon: Pokemon {
        let fetchRequest = Pokemon.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        let result = try! fetch(fetchRequest)
        return result.first!
    }

    // put other fetch helpers in here too!
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm already doing, except I'm not using @ObservedObject. What I want is to not have to do that extra fetch request to get a Pokemon in the preview. I already have a sample pokemon in the PersistenceController which I can use for my ContentView, and I want to use it for my other views too.